# export dataframe to csv staking the columns with header and date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe that I'd like to export to a csv file where each column is stacked on top of one another.  I want to use each header as a label with the date in this format, Allu_1_2013.

```
date         Allu_1    Allu_2  Alluv_3  year
2013-01-01    2.00      1.45   3.54     2013
2014-01-01    3.09      2.35   9.01     2014
2015-01-01    4.79      4.89   10.04    2015
```

The final csv text tile should look like

```
Allu_1_2013    2.00         
Allu_1_2014    3.09         
Allu_1_2015    4.79         
Allu_2_2013    1.45
Allu_2_2014    2.35
Allu_2_2015    4.89
Allu_3_2013    3.54
Allu_3_2014    9.01
Allu_3_2015    10.04
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
new_df = df.melt(id_vars=["date", "year"], 
        var_name="Date", 
        value_name="Value").drop(columns=['date'])

new_df['idx'] = new_df['Date'] + '_' + new_df['year'].astype(str)
new_df = new_df.drop(columns=['year', 'Date'])
```

|  | Value | idx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | Allu_1_2013 |
| 1 | 3.09 | Allu_1_2014 |
| 2 | 4.79 | Allu_1_2015 |
| 3 | 1.45 | Allu_2_2013 |
| 4 | 2.35 | Allu_2_2014 |
| 5 | 4.89 | Allu_2_2015 |
| 6 | 3.54 | Alluv_3_2013 |
| 7 | 9.01 | Alluv_3_2014 |
| 8 | 10.04 | Alluv_3_2015 |